# Scala: Getting the clean class name

Tags: scala

Upon digging it seems this is a sensitive issue.

```
  class TestNames {

    private[this] lazy val _name: String = this.getClass.getName.split("\\.").last
    def name: String = _name

  }

  class Parent extends TestNames
  class Parent2 extends Parent

class ClassNameExtraction extends FlatSpec {

  it should "correctly extract the table name" in {
    object TestNames extends TestNames

    assert(TestNames.name === "TestNames")
  } 

  it should "correctly extract the parent name" in {
    object Parent extends Parent

    assert(Parent.name === "Parent")
  }

  it should "correctly extract the column names" in {
    object Parent2 extends Parent2

    assert((Parent2.name === "Parent2"))
  }
}
```

I can see there is a simple pattern: `$$annonfun$number$ + ACTUAL_CLASS_NAME + $number$`.
Is there a simpler way of doing this?

**Update:**

Got something working without inheritance:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
class SomeClass {
  private[this] lazy val _name: String = implicitly[ClassTag[this.type]].runtimeClass.getSimpleName
  def name: String = _name
}
```

However this returns the same name in sub classes:

```
class SomeOtherClass extends SomeClass {}
object SomeOtherClass extends SomeOtherClass
SomeOtherClass.name// is still SomeClass
```

Comment: I suspect part of the problem is related to the test itself. Try moving `TestNames`, `Parent` and `Parent2` outside the test, having some `val` in the test point to the `*.name`, and the compare the `val` instead of `*.name`.

Comment: You may also experiment without the `lazy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue:

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2034

Do you need a class per se or a type name?  Because that's what reflection is for.

The policy is not to discuss religion, politics or name mangling.